# Should I use schema.org for a suggestion box and Q&A website?

Tags: seo, schema.org

I'm currently working on a getSatisfaction site like, where user will be able to post ideas, and question on various subjets.
Should I use schema.org on Ideas & Questions ? And which schema could I use ?

I was maybe thinking of using the http://schema.org/CreativeWork schema.

I'm already using its children BlogPosting for a Blog I have developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an appropriate schema for a Q&A format. I wouldn't use one that isn't appropriate but at best it confuses Google and hurts your ranks. At worst it is seen as abuse and gets you penalized.